# AWS CLI Filter codecommit repositories by date of modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to do a query that only return to me the repos that was modified in the last one year.

So I'm trying the following command:

```
aws codecommit list-repositories --query 'repositories[?lastModifiedDate>=`'"$(date --date='1 month ago' +%s.0000000)"'`]' --output text
```

But when I use it, nothing return. Someone can point me the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use JMESPath query with `list-repositorie` to get `lastModifiedDate` because this one returns only two parameters `repositoryName` and `repositoryId`

```
[
    {
        "repositoryName": "test",
        "repositoryId": "aaaaaa-bbbbb-cccc-dddd-aaaaaaaa"
    }
]
```

Instead, you can combine both `list-repositorie` and `get-repository` in a bash script for example to solve your problem for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all repositories in the account
repositories=$(aws codecommit list-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryName' --output text)
echo $repositories
# Loop through each repository and get its details
for repo in $repositories
do
  echo "Repository: $repo"
  details=$(aws codecommit get-repository --repository-name $repo --query 'repositoryMetadata.lastModifiedDate' --output text)
  echo $details
done
```

Sorry I'm not expert in bash, but the idea is here, you have all the elements, you need just to filter by `lastModifiedDate` to get what you need.

Comment: Excellent idea! I'm trying to use the same expression to filter the ModifiedDate in the get-repository command, but still receiving nothing: aws codecommit get-repository --repository-name $repo --query 'repositoryMetadata[?lastModifiedDate>`'"$(date --date="1 year ago" +%Y-%m-%dT%T.000000-03:00)"'']'